# Скрипт четной и не четной суммы чисел

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, решил тут на досуге сделать счетчик для игры в настольный тенис. 
Задачи которые он должен выполнять:
- Увеличивать счет при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку
- При нажатии на кнопку "Партия" обнулять счет
- Отображать чья сейчас подача
Так вот, первых 2 пункта я сделал, а вот с третьим есть проблема. В тенисе подача переходит к другому игроку когда счет четный, тоесть когда игрок подаст 2 подачи, например когда счет 2-0, 1-1, 8-6, 7-5 и т.д. У меня есть 2 картинки шарика у которых visibility = 'hidden', и когда сумма счета делиться на 2 то менять у них свойства на visibility = 'hidden'и visibility = 'visible' 
Вот как я это реализовал:

```js
var $leftScore = document.getElementById('lscore');
  var $rightScore = document.getElementById('rscore');
    leftSum = 0;
    rightSum = 0;

function lcounter() {
  $leftScore.innerHTML = ++leftSum;;
  onUpdate();
}

function rcounter() {
  $rightScore.innerHTML = ++rightSum;
  onUpdate();
}

function reset() {
  $leftScore.innerHTML = leftSum = 0;
  $rightScore.innerHTML = rightSum = 0;
  document.getElementById('lBall').style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('rBall').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function onUpdate() {
  var x = (+leftSum + +rightSum) % 2 == 0;
  var y = (+leftSum + +rightSum);

  if ((+leftSum + +rightSum) % 2 == 0) {
    document.getElementById('lBall').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('rBall').style.visibility = 'hidden';
       // sum % 2 = 1
  } 
  else {
    document.getElementById('rBall').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('lBall').style.visibility = 'hidden';
       // sum % 2 = 0
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #0d3573;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 159px;
}
.bottom {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left_score {
  color: red;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right_score {
  color: blue;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.ball {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: orange;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.ball img {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#reset{
  font-size: 15px;
}
#rBall{
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#lBall{
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="section left_ball">
            <div class="ball" id="lBall" style="visibility:visible">
               <div src="img/ball.png" alt="ball">
            </div>
          </div>
      <div class="section left_score score" id="lscore">0</div>
      <div class="section right_score score" id="rscore">0</div>
      <div class="section right_ball">
          <div class="ball" id="rBall">
            <div src="img/ball.png" alt="ball">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="section left plus" id="leftPlus">
        <button id="lbutton" onclick="lcounter()" class="myBtn">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="section reset" id="rightPlus">
        <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">партия</button>
      </div>
      <div class="section right plus" id="rightPlus">
        <button id="rbutton" onclick="rcounter()" class="myBtn">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Но проблема в том, что свойства меняються при каждом увеличении счета, а не только когда счет делиться на 2. Я думаю тут немного неправильная логика. 2й день не могу придумать как правильно реализовать этот момент :(
[Вот страница](https://artemchepeliuk.github.io/tenis_score/)

Comment: Я в теннисе не силен. Когда должна меняться подача? Когда общий счет четный? Или распишите более подробно алгоритм.

Comment: Подача должна меняться когда один игрок подал 2 подачи, тоесть когда счет делиться на 2, например: 2-0, 1-1, 3-1, 8-2

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста рабочий сниппет в вашем вопросе, что бы на его базе можно было дать ответ.

Comment: мне нужно что бы при смене счета блоки с шариками показывались или срывались  в зависимости от счета, если сума счета четная то один шарик пропадает, а другой появляется. Есть функция Update() которая меняет видимость блоков, но она меняет пр и каждом увеличении счета, а должна менять только при увеличении счета на 2

Comment: Код добавили, сразу вам и ответили)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере всегда срабатывает или `if` или `else`. Потому и шарик все время появляется, так как число либо четное, либо нет. А вам надо менять отображение только если число делиться на 2 сразу у обоих `div`.

```js
var $leftScore = document.getElementById('lscore');
var $rightScore = document.getElementById('rscore');
var leftBall =  document.getElementById('lBall');
var rigthBall =  document.getElementById('rBall');
    leftSum = 0;
    rightSum = 0;

function lcounter() {
   $leftScore.innerHTML = ++leftSum;
  onUpdate();
}

function rcounter() {
  $rightScore.innerHTML = ++rightSum;
  onUpdate();
}

function reset() {
  $leftScore.innerHTML = leftSum = 0;
  $rightScore.innerHTML = rightSum = 0;
  document.getElementById('lBall').style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('rBall').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function onUpdate() {
  if ((+leftSum + +rightSum) % 2 === 0) {
    leftBall.style.visibility = leftBall.style.visibility == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
    rigthBall.style.visibility = rigthBall.style.visibility == "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden";

  } 
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #0d3573;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  background-image: url('/img/tabl.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 159px;
}
.bottom {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left_score {
  color: red;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right_score {
  color: blue;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.ball {
  max-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ball img {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#reset{
  font-size: 15px;
}
#rBall{
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#lBall{
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="section left_ball">
            <div class="ball" id="lBall" style="visibility: hidden;">
              <img src="img/ball.png" alt="ball">
            </div>
          </div>
      <div class="section left_score score" id="lscore">17</div>
      <div class="section right_score score" id="rscore">0</div>
      <div class="section right_ball">
          <div class="ball" id="rBall" style="visibility: visible;">
            <img src="img/ball.png" alt="ball">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">



      <div class="section left plus" id="leftPlus">
        <button id="lbutton" onclick="lcounter()" class="myBtn">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="section reset" id="rightPlus">
        <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">партия</button>
      </div>

      <div class="section right plus" id="rightPlus">
        <button id="rbutton" onclick="rcounter()" class="myBtn">+</button>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает))

Comment: Отлично, если вам все подходит, примите, пожалуйста, ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var players = [0 , 0];
var i = 0;
function podacha() {
 let rand = Math.random();
 let random = Math.round(rand);
 i++;
 players[random]++;
 //alert(players);
 document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById('first').innerHTML = players[0];
 document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = "";
 document.getElementById('second').innerHTML = players[1];
 if(i%2 == 0) {
  var a1 = document.getElementById('FIrst');
  a1.classList.toggle('class1');
  var a2 = document.getElementById('SEcond');
  a2.classList.toggle('class1');
 }
}
```

```css
.class1 {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 



 <button id="podacha" onclick="podacha()">сюда!!</button>
 <span id="first">0</span>  :  
 <span id="second">0</span> <br>
 <span id="FIrst">подает первый</span> <br>
 <span id="SEcond" class="class1">подает второй</span>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

с придумыванием именами переменных у меня проблемы,
но ты разберешся

Comment: код работает, но немного не так как мне нужно.мне нужно что бы не рандомно числа брались, а из блоков со счетом, скину полный код что бы бало понятней

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $leftScore = document.getElementById('lscore');
var $rightScore = document.getElementById('rscore');
var leftBall =  document.getElementById('lBall');
var rigthBall =  document.getElementById('rBall');
    leftSum = 0;
    rightSum = 0;

function lcounter() {
   $leftScore.innerHTML = ++leftSum;
  onUpdate();
}

function rcounter() {
  $rightScore.innerHTML = ++rightSum;
  onUpdate();
}

function reset() {
  $leftScore.innerHTML = leftSum = 0;
  $rightScore.innerHTML = rightSum = 0;
  document.getElementById('lBall').style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('rBall').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function onUpdate() {
  if ((+leftSum + +rightSum) % 2 === 0) {
    document.getElementById('lBall').classList.toggle("hide");
    document.getElementById('rBall').classList.toggle("hide");

  } 
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #0d3573;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  background-image: url('/img/tabl.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 159px;
}
.bottom {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left_score {
  color: red;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

.right_score {
  color: blue;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.ball {
  max-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ball img {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#reset{
  font-size: 15px;
}
#rBall{
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#lBall{
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.hide {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 


<div class="main">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="section left_ball">
            <div class="ball" id="lBall">
               <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg" alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
      <div class="section left_score score" id="lscore">0</div>
      <div class="section right_score score" id="rscore">0</div>
      <div class="section right_ball">
          <div class="ball hide" id="rBall">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="section left plus" id="leftPlus">
        <button id="lbutton" onclick="lcounter()" class="myBtn">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="section reset" id="rightPlus">
        <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">партия</button>
      </div>
      <div class="section right plus" id="rightPlus">
        <button id="rbutton" onclick="rcounter()" class="myBtn">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```